# Running mysql commands in bash script generating errors

Tags: mysql, bash, unix

Running a bash script executing MySQL commands, I get an error on this line.

```
$MYSQL_BIN $DATABASE -e \
"ALTER TABLE `nodes` ADD COLUMN `created_date` int(32) AFTER `address`";
```

The error is **created_date: command not found**

As well as on this line:

```
$MYSQL_BIN $DATABASE -e \
"UPDATE `nodes` SET `created_date` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE `created_date` 
IS NULL AND `address` IS NOT NULL";
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SET  = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
>   WHERE  IS NULL AND  IS NOT NULL' at
>   line 1.

I believe the first error is because I'm probably not escaping quotes?

Comment: Use single quotes '' instead of "" around your SQL statement, or escape \` in it. Bash uses `` to execute commands inline.

Answer (score 4):

Bash uses bactick operator (`` ` ``) to indicate command substitution, that is, substitution of the standard output from one command into a line of text defining another command.

So you should either use single quotes instead of double ones or escape the backticks properly:

```
$MYSQL_BIN $DATABASE -e 
'ALTER TABLE `nodes` ADD COLUMN `created_date` int(32) AFTER `address`';
```

or

```
$MYSQL_BIN $DATABASE -e 
"ALTER TABLE \`nodes\` ADD COLUMN \`created_date\` int(32) AFTER \`address\`";
```

Comment: One is left wondering what the `nodes` command generated as output.  But that's not a problem with your answer - just with the OP's environment.

Comment: There is no command named `nodes` on a standart *NIX (at least Linux) installation, so the output is most probably `-bash: nodes: command not found`.

Comment: I wonder if we got all the error messages; there was also the command `address` too.  Nice to know there isn't a standard command by the name 'nodes' - thanks.